# FDTD Poynting Vector

Tags: finite-difference

I'm attempting to validate my FDTD code against Meep by calculating the Poynting vector field across a simulation consisting of a monochromatic point source within a box (no boundary conditions (Dirichlet) so everything just bounces off the domain boundaries.

In this case, the simulation is 2D TMz (point source in $E{z}$, coupling into $H{x}$ and $H{y}$).

After quite a bit of research and talking with my thesis advisor, I wound up using this for Poynting vector $\hat{P}$ calculation:

$\hat{E} \times \hat{H}^*$ (complex conjugate is the same as the original $H$ vector in this case since everything is in the real domain).

$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \hat{P}_X\\
  \hat{P}_Y\\
  \hat{P}_Z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
E_YH_Z - E_zH_Y\\
E_zH_X - E_XH_Z\\
E_XH_Y - E_YH_X\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Given that 
$\hat{E} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & E_Z\end{bmatrix}$
and 
$\hat{H} = \begin{bmatrix}H_X & H_Y & 0\end{bmatrix}$

(since there are no $E_X$, $E_Y$, or $H_Z$ components in a 2D TMz sim)

$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \hat{P}_X\\
  \hat{P}_Y\\
  \hat{P}_Z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
- E_ZH_Y\\
E_ZH_X\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$

When calculating the Poynting vector field, I iterate through the entire $E_Z$ array, and use the above formula for obtaining the $P$ vector at each cell. Then, basic algebra to get the magnitude and direction:

$|P| = \sqrt{P_X^2 + P_Y^2 + P_Z^2}
\\
\\
P_{normal} = {P \over{|P|}}
$

Now, plotting the magnitude before the source wave hits the boundary of the simulation ($E_Z$ pictured below),
[image: Ez just before the wave hits the boundary]

I would expect the Poynting vector magnitude field to resemble a cone, indicating that the magnitude falls off with $1\over{R^2}$ distance $R$ from the source position.

However, I'm seeing this:

[image]

Now, my question is: does my math look right? Or, am I missing something here? Any suggestions or links to example code are welcome.

Even a picture of what the Poynting magnitude and direction field should look like for a monochromatic point source would be helpful.

Comment: Can you try running the code with a much smaller grid size and see what happens? If your result looks nicer, then you can chalk it up to grid resolution, otherwise it'll be something more complicated.

Comment: @DanielShapero by "smaller grid size," do you mean higher resolution, or a smaller domain? The grid is already dense enough to meet the FDTD stability requirement, but if I need something denser for the Poynting vector, I can give it a shot.

Comment: I was thinking higher resolution. Getting a good estimate of the Poynting vector shouldn't require a finer grid than for the $E$ and $H$ fields themselves, so if your grid satisfies the stability requirement it should work just fine. Nonetheless, running it at higher resolution might be illuminating.

Comment: @DanielShapero Higher res helped quite a bit. Turned out the problem was a floating point precision error. :/ So I cranked up the source amplitude, got it working, dialed it back, and adjusted a few other things to keep everything in a reasonable range. (This is running on consumer-grade GPUs, most of which don't support `double`.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidLively, you can create an answer to your own question and accept it. That would remove the question from the list of unanswered and will be useful as it is quite popular.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Done! I do that frequently on StackOverflow, neglected to do it here. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much deliberation, I tracked down the problem to a few software bugs:

1. An array index is not a field value.
2. Floating point precision is a factor when squaring a *VERY* small number.
3. `NaN` really isn't a number, and trying to normalize a zero-length vector requires careful thought.
4. The really big misconception on my part: since the power flows between adjacent E points via connecting H points, and the source is a sinusoid, the magnitude (and Poynting vector) will, of course, oscillate. I've added a pair of RMS calculations that looks at the average and peak values over a period, and I'm getting something more like what I expected.

Ultimately, my math was correct, but my implementation had a few issues. Thankfully it was on the Poynting vector calculation side rather than the FDTD side.

[image]